# Which layers are more intolerant to error in neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, layer, gradient-descent

I am doing research and am curious about the impact of gradient descent on layers individually. As we all know, gradient descent always tries to takes us to the global minimum of the valley. However, I wonder if we can consider any single layer as most responsible for getting to the deepest location. Otherwise, is it possible that earlier or later layers are more or less tolerant to incorrect weight updates? Comments are welcome, however any paper that addresses this issue would be great.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Notice also that SO is *not* a discussion forum, and questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic here.